# Undefined offset: 32 in php when fetching an array

Tags: php, html, arrays, mysqli, phpmyadmin

```
<?php                                        
$uid  = $_SESSION['UID'];
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT user.*,score.* from `user` join score ON user.USERID=score.USERID WHERE user.USERID='$uid'  ");
if (!$result) {
     printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
     exit();
}

function dataBlock($row) {
    return "<td>".$row['SCORE']."</td>".
           "<td>".$row['AVERAGE']."</td>".
           "<td>".$row['POINTS']."</td>";
 }

$numModules = 4;
$rows = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[$row['USERID']][$row['ACTCODE']].push(dataBlock($row));
}

foreach($rows as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($k = 0 ; $k < $numModules; $k++) {
        echo $row[$k];
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}?>
```

**Current Output**

[image]
**my desired output** is if the value of the **ACTCODE of the USER** in the database is 1 then it should be in output of the lesson exam row, 2 if in module 1 row and 3 if in module 2 row and so on

[image]

The error is showing in this line 
  **$rows[$row['USERID']][$row['ACTCODE']].push(dataBlock($row));**

Comment: `.push` is not valid PHP in that context. What you actually want is `$rows[$row['USERID']][$row['ACTCODE']][] = dataBlock($row);`

Comment: after trying the code there is an error Undefined offset: 0 in   echo $row[$k]; @Nick

Comment: In that foreach, `$row` will be an array which is indexed by the values of `ACTCODE` that came out of your database. So there's no guarantee that it will have a  `0` index. You probably should use a foreach instead e.g. `foreach ($row as $v) { echo $v; }`

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the `$row` array incorrectly. If you're using a WHILE loop you need to specify an index and increment it on each pass of the loop

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
  $rows[$row[$i]['USERID']][$row[$i]['ACTCODE']].push(dataBlock($row));
  $i++;
}
```

The reason is that `$row` becomes an array when you assign the output from the database and each row retrieved from the database gets indexed as an array element. A `print_r($row)` would show something similar to this:

```
$row => array(
   [0] => array(
      [USERID] => row 0 content 1
      [ACTCODE] => row 0 content 2
      )
   [1] => array(
      [USERID] => row 1 content 1
      [ACTCODE] => row 1 content 2
      )
   [2] => array(
      [USERID] => row 2 content 1
      [ACTCODE] => row 2 content 2
      )
)
```

That's just a rough example, but it helps visualizing the explanation a little better

Comment: This is not correct. `$row` will be an array with keys `USERID, ACTCODE, etc.`.

Comment: Yes and no. Keys will in fact be USERID, ACTCODE and whatever else is in the query result, but `$row`will be indexed with the row number. Otherwise, there would be no way to get a specific line of the result within the array. Doing a `print_r($row)` confirms it